# Storing variables within a function

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

How can I store variables locally within a function.

```
testing <- function(number.info){
  if (!exists('x')){
    x <- 0
  }
    x <- x + number.info
  return(x)
}
testing(2)
testing(2)
```

As we see here every time I run the function it returns the same value, as x is not being stored.

The motivation behind this is to create a function that can accrue information.

EDIT: Not a repeat question, i did check this answer before hand. The reason is that I don't need it useable outside the function. I just want the function to store it so as i input more data it outputs a 'smarter' result using this new information. I want to do with without using the global environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the value to the global environment. Or the environment you are working from:

```
testing <- function(number.info){
  if (!exists('x')){
    x <- 0
  }
  x <- x + number.info
  list2env(list(x=x),.GlobalEnv)
  return(x)
}
testing(2)
[1] 2
testing(2)
[1] 4
```

If you do want to create a new environment then you can do something like:

```
myenv=new.env()
testing <- function(number.info){

  if (!exists('x',envir = myenv)){
    assign("x", 0,envir = myenv)
  }
  x=get("x",envir = myenv) + number.info
  assign("x", x,envir = myenv)

  return(x)
}
testing(2)
[1] 2
testing(2)
[1] 4
```